# Adding multiple instances of Model3DGroup to ModelVisual3D

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-4.0

I am working on building a graphical model in WPF that should be of a three-dimensional truss eventually. I am building a single object as a Model3DGroup. I am then adding that Model3DGroup to a ModelVisual3D.

Currently, I am declaring in my *.xaml.cs file `private ModelVisual3D mGeometry;` at the top. Then, a new Model3DGroup is created, where several points triangle models are added. Then, the following code is used to add this to the ModelVisual3D:

```
mGeometry.Content = prism; // where prism is the Model3D Group with added triangle points
mGeometry.Transform = new Transform3DGroup();
this.viewport.Children.Add(mGeometry);
```

My question is: how do I add multiple different instances of Model3DGroup to one ModelVisual3D? I eventually want to build a truss composed of multiple different Model3DGroups and display it on the screen.

I'm not opposed to changing how I do this, as I'm not sure the best way. Currently, I can only display one object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each `ModelVisual3D` can contain just 1 `Model3D` but can also contain other `Visual3D`s. In this case you can just add more `ModelVisual3D`s to the `Children` property of your `ModelVisual3D`:

```
mGeometry.Content = prism;
var moreModelVisual3D = new ModelVisual3D();
moreModelVisual3D.Content = prism2; //your other Model3DGroup
mGeometry.Children.Add(moreModelVisual3D);
//create more if you want ...
```

Also note that each `Model3DGroup` can contain other `Model3DGroup`s. If you think that can be applied in your case, please consider it instead.